# window.opener is undefined on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am trying to access an element of my Parent window from a Pop-up window, I am getting `window.opener` as undefined.

```
var opener = window.opener;
if(opener) 
{
    console.log("opener element found");
    var elem = opener.$('.my-parent-element');
    if (elem) {
        console.log("parent element found");
        elem.show(); 
    }
}
```

Here `opener` is undefined. Am I doing something wrong?

I have tried `parent.window.opener` / `window.top` / `window.top.document.body`etc., but it doesn't help either. It works fine in other browsers.

I have see the question [***Window Opener Alternative***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885765/window-opener-alternatives), but I cannot change opening my popup with `showModalDialog` right away. Probably, this would be last option.

Comment: Is the opener the same host? Has it been redirecting?

Comment: Then I think it has to do with IE security zones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822885/window-opener-null-on-same-domain-in-ie

Comment: That sounds a problem of my kind. But does not seem to have a solution? Is it?

Comment: Like many IE problems unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `showModalDialog` function and pass arguments to it, if the browser used is IE. Simply pass `window` object as an argument.

After that you can access the arguments from the modal window using `dialogArguments`.

More details can be found in the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533723%28VS.85%29.aspx

Example of retrieve:

```
window.showModalDialog(theURL, window);

//in the modal dialog you can use this to retrieve the window.
var openerWindow = window.dialogArguments;
```

Comment: Sorry for being late. As I said before implementing with `showModalDialog` would be the last option(so it took some time). I changed my code and ran. All fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem and it was due to Internet Explorer Security Options,
in particular because my popup was going to an External website (Internet area) and the parent was an internal page (Intranet area). 
The "Protected Mode" was only activated for the "Internet".
I activated it for the "Local intranet" and now it works.

To find this option in IE:

- Go to Internet Options
- Security tab
- Click on "Internet" or "Local intranet" icon
- Check or uncheck the option "Enable Protected Mode"
- Restart IE