# Auth0 IE Issue: Unable to get property 'frames' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs, oauth

I am using the Angular + Auth0 seed project and everything works as expected in Chrome, but in IE 11, I get the following error when trying to login with Google, Microsoft, etc. credentials:

Unable to get property 'frames' of undefined or null reference

It specifically calls out the following and fails on the line for var frames = window.opener.frames with the error message: Unable to get property 'frames' of undefined or null reference

```
 function findRelay() {
var loc = window.location;
var frames = window.opener.frames;
for (var i = frames.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  try {
    if (frames[i].location.protocol === window.location.protocol &&
        frames[i].location.host === window.location.host &&
        frames[i].name === RELAY_FRAME_NAME)
    {
      return frames[i];
    }
  } catch(e) { }
}
return;
```

}

Any clues?

Comment: I am also getting this error.

Comment: This issue went away when I published my site and only appeared while testing using Visual Studio and IE. It works in Chrome. It could be how IIS Express ran by VS is rendering out. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am getting this error only with Internet Explorer. I am trying to debug from Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26359243/23059.
I enabled `protected mode` for `local intranet` so that it matched `internet` `protected mode`.