# Why does setting Enable Protected Mode have an effect on whether or not window.opener is null?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I was having a problem that was similar to this developer.

[window.opener is undefined on Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562044/window-opener-is-undefined-on-internet-explorer?lq=1)

In IE10, users were getting an error when accessing a pop-up and then returning because window.opener was null.  The pop-up branched out to a third-party website and was then redirected to a URL in the same domain as the parent window.

I had them follow the last solution in this question: to check "Enable Protected Mode" for Trusted sites (which includes the third-party site), and this fixed the issue.

My question is WHY?  Why does this work?  If anything, I would think that the user would have to uncheck that setting.  Is it a question of the settings simply having to *match* for both the Internet and Trusted sites?  And is this specific to IE10?

Any information would be appreciated...thanks!