# call angular component method from external window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm working on twitter login in my ASP .NET web application using Angular 2.
I want to pass data from the pop-up window to the component .I have used the method mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997625/angular-2-communication-of-typescript-functions-with-external-js-libraries/36997723#36997723).
But the callback to the component is not working.

Below is the code that loads in the external login window

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('socialSuccess'));
```

and in the component from which the pop-up window is invoked i have written the callback

```
 @HostListener('window:socialSuccess', ['$event'])

  onSocialSuccess(event) {
    alert("here");
    this.PopUpCallback(event)

  }
```

The **onSocialSuccess** method is not getting called.

Please guide

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying would not work, as you mentioned in your question that you are using twitter login API which opens a pop-up window to login.

The reason is, there are two windows, so you are having two different objects of `window`.

One is the main window (maybe your app window) and another one is the pop-up window.

**Solution :**

Let say you want to pass data from pop-up window to main window, so in your pop-up window, you should use the above method you tried already but with a caution that you use `window.opener.disp...`

The only difference this makes is, `window.opener` is the parent window which initiated the pop-up.

Note: `window.opener` might not work in IE, so you can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562044/window-opener-is-undefined-on-internet-explorer) for IE Browser.

Hope it helps :)